# GAS web app, Javascript Table, doesnt sort properly on dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4, web-applications

I have a table to consult data of what I have eaten

When I click to sort by the first column which is the date, it seems to do it fine except for the fact that it puts all the 10s right between 1 and 2, similarly with 20s, then after 3, it puts 30 and then 4,5,6,7,8 and 9

Example:
8/2/2021    Skim Milk -Protein+, Hacendado  426

8/2/2021    -Calories   150

8/2/2021    -Calories   189

8/2/2021    -Calories   230

8/10/2021   4 Cheese Pizza, Hacendado   49

8/10/2021   4 Cheese Pizza, Hacendado   91

8/10/2021   4 Cheese Pizza, Hacendado   87

8/10/2021   Totters Mini Animals Cereals, Dia   80

8/10/2021   Whole Milk, Hacendado   265

8/1/2021    -Fat    10

8/1/2021    Egg 176

8/1/2021    -Calories   550

8/1/2021    Chicken McNuggets   160

8/1/2021    Chocolate Pudding, Danone -Unit 100

8/1/2021    -Calories   100

7/31/2021   -Calories   1030

Dont mind the content of the 2 right columns

Here is the code

Code gs

```
  function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  }

  //GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
  function getData() {
    var spreadSheetId = "~longnumber~~dontmindthis~";                         //Google Sheet ID
    var dataRange = "FoodLogData!A2:C";                                                           //Data Sheet & Range

    var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
    var values = range.values;

    return values;
  }

  
  function include(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
  }
```

Index HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?><!--INCLUDE JavaScript.html FILE-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
          <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Javascript HTML

```
  <script>
    /*
    *THIS FUNCTION CALL THE getData() FUNCTION IN THE Code.gs FILE, 
    *AND PASS RETURNED DATA TO showData() FUNCTION
    */
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();

    //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY
    function showData(dataArray){
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#data-table').DataTable({
          data: dataArray,
          //CHANGE THE TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
          columns: [
            {"title":"Date"},
            {"title":"Food"},
            {"title":"Grams/%"}
            
          ]
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You can use the DataTables [date/time sorting plug-in](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) for this. This will sort dates by chronological order, instead of by alphabetic order. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159588/datatables-how-to-sort-by-date-dd-mm-yyyy/68163742#68163742) - except in your case, you only have one date format that you need to handle.

Comment: It seems to be sorting the dates as strings.  Try formatting them as dates

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/50836008/1595451

Answer (score 1):

I split the data on spaces so I probably messed up some of the columns (you could have avoided that by providing the data as a table).

I formatted them as dates and resorted:

| 8/1/2021 | -Fat | 10 |  |  | 426 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2021 | Egg | 176 |  |  |  |  |
| 8/1/2021 | -Calories | 550 |  |  |  |  |
| 8/1/2021 | Chicken | McNuggets | 160 |  |  |  |
| 8/1/2021 | Chocolate | Pudding, | Danone | -Unit | 49 |  |
| 8/1/2021 | -Calories | 100 |  |  | 91 |  |
| 8/2/2021 | Skim | Milk | -Protein+, | Hacendado | 87 |  |
| 8/2/2021 | -Calories | 150 |  |  | Dia | 80 |
| 8/2/2021 | -Calories | 189 |  |  |  |  |
| 8/2/2021 | -Calories | 230 |  |  |  |  |
| 8/10/2021 | 4 | Cheese | Pizza, | Hacendado |  |  |
| 8/10/2021 | 4 | Cheese | Pizza, | Hacendado |  |  |
| 8/10/2021 | 4 | Cheese | Pizza, | Hacendado |  |  |
| 8/10/2021 | Totters | Mini | Animals | Cereals, | 100 |  |
| 8/10/2021 | Whole | Milk, | Hacendado | 265 |  |  |

You can use setNumberFormat on ranges